# Creating a pandas column with a list of words in a text feature for an instance

Tags: pandas, text

I'm trying to extract only a select list of words from a pandas column that is a paragraph, creating a column of ONLY those words if they're present (this is the indicators list). When I apply the custom function, I keep getting random batches of letters. Here's my attempt at a function that doesn't work:

```
indicators = "|".join(("banana tree", "climate change", "warming", "dinosaurs"))

def indication_find(x):
    for words in x:
         if words in indicators:
            return words
         else:
            pass

df["indicators"] = df["text"].apply(indication_find)
```

The input would be a couple of sentences written by a student, and teh output would be only those words that I'm filtering for in the list.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by extracting only a select list of words. But based on the documentation you are using str.extract wrong. It takes a regular expression and returns where it finds a match for the expression: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: right you are. Question edited, and thank you!

Comment: I am still not clear on the goal. Can you give an example of input df and expected results?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't post any of the sample data. Sucks for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few modification to your code. Indicators should be a list of strings. What you had was one big string and when you loop through it, it will go through each letter in that string not words. So do this instead:

```
indicators = ["banana tree", "climate change", "warming", "dinosaurs"]
```

In your custom function x will be a string containing the whole paragraph. So you need to split it by space so that you get a list of words.

```
def indication_find(x):
    list_of_words = x.split(' ')
    out_data = [] # initialize an empty list
    for word in list_of_words :
        # remove punctuations with strip() 
         if word.strip('.,!?') in indicators:
            out_data.append(word)
    return str(out_data)

df["indicators"] = df["text"].apply(indication_find)
```

Comment: for some reason, word.strip() is returning a "can't assign to function call." If I drop that, it works beautifully... but I lose out on all of the things with punctuation.

Comment: Sorry it should be just all characters in one string.